# How to deserialize xml data from c# to java?

Tags: c#, java, xml, serialization

I have identical objects in both a c# server app and a java client app. The server XML serializes these objects and makes them available through a REST service.  The java app downloads the data in XML format.  What is the best way to deserialize the xml data to my java objects?  I am currently using Java org.w3c.dom classes to parse the xml and create new objects. I understand that certain types like dates and byte arrays will have to be handled manually, but a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

C# Class:

```
public class Sample {
    public string MyText { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
    //many more fields
}
```

Java Class:

```
public class Sample {
    public String MyText;
    public boolean Flag;
}
```

Here is the xml thats coming from the c# web app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sample xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <MyText>Blah Blah</MyText>
    <Flag>false</Flag>
</Sample>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach on the Java end is to use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org). It offers a trivial means of deserialising XML to Java objects, without requiring a schema definition.

XStream will normally expect Java class/package names as XML elements. However you can modify this behaviour through the use of aliases. Given the above requirements you'll need this facility. See [this tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Why not serialize to JSON in C# then deserialize in Java. Both platforms have JSON support / libraries.  From the C# side you can use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/).  JSON will produce a light-weight file much smaller than XML and should be a bit faster when processing.

Comment: I would like to use this approach, however existing systems are already using this data format.

Answer (score 1):

[JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) is a way of binding an xml schema to Java classes.  You can even generate your classes from a schema or dtd.  Or you can manually annotate your java classes with xpath like expressions that tell JAXB how to deserialize XML.

If that is a little heavyweight then Java offers many choices of how to read xml from a file.  I like [commons digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/), and Sun's newish [streaming api for xml](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) library, used as Java deserialization solution, looks quite promising.